# Filters on the_content with plugins, pages and shortcode

Tags: plugins, shortcode, filters, the-content

I am using a plugin to add tweet, likes... This plugin add filters to `the_content()` to display this social buttons on a blog page (list of posts).

I coded a shortcode which does a custom SQL query which displays posts. 
I even added `apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() )` for these filters to be applied on `get_the_content()`.
I added the shortcode on a page. The only one problem is that the buttons "like", "tweet" are not "linked" to the different posts but to the page.

For instance, on one post, i have 2 likes and 10 tweets in a normal way and they are displayed on this page with a count of 0. I believe this buttons are in fact linked to the page and not to the posts. I tried with adding other plugins like voting, it is the same: the vote on the posts are not displayed..

I just want this buttons to be displayed like in a normal post loop. Is it a way to add this filters on `the_content()` in the shortcode loop and not in the `the_content` in the page. The blog list works well, votes and buttons are correctly displayed. I want the same behavior on a page with a shortcode displaying posts, is it possible?

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alternative solution, I had just to use a new template with the loop to avoid this problem witha loop in shortcodes and everything  works well for now.